# Can I implement SQL Server Service Broker in python?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Is it possible to implement a service broker to receive messages from SQL Server in a language like Python, or does it always have to be in some .Net language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible (but not much fun)

Service Broker is configured and used via T-SQL commands, so if you have a way to talk to SQL Server from python (e.g. using the excellent [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc)) then you just have to connect and issue the appropriate queries. Figuring out the appropriate T-SQL and getting Service Broker to work for you is the hard part, not the python bit.

```python
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(your_connection_string)
conn.autocommit = True
conn.execute("ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE")

# ... etc ...
```

The rest of the (many hundreds of lines of) SQL is an exercise in understanding Service Broker, for which there is much MSDN documentation, such as [the Developer's Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522908(v=sql.105).aspx) for SQL Server 2008 R2.

The community tutorials are very useful for figuring out stuff that Microsoft doesn't tell you e.g. these which I found helpful enough to get a proof-of-concept running before I gave it up :)

- http://rusanu.com/2006/04/06/fire-and-forget-good-for-the-military-but-not-for-service-broker-conversations/
- http://www.davewentzel.com/content/service-broker-demystified-fire-and-forget-anti-pattern
- http://www.davewentzel.com/content/service-broker-demystified-default-not-default

Comment: So basically issue T-SQL commands but via python, is your solution. Thanks for all the links anyway. Will need to check them out.